# Facebook PHP SDK error mb_substr

Tags: php, facebook, heroku

I am following [this](http://metah.ch/blog/2014/05/facebook-sdk-4-0-0-for-php-a-working-sample-to-get-started/#post-937) code for my fb app . I host this app on Heroku. When I login its shows this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Facebook\mb_substr() in /app/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php on line 253
```

Any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: ops , problem is I select this from mobile apps :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable the `mbstring` extension: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions

In your `composer.json`, the `require` block needs to contain it, like so:

```
{
  "require": {
    "ext-mbstring": "*"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to enable the:
**mbstring** extension

Have a look on the following page:
http://en.blog.candycane.jp/2012/04/11/running-php-on-heroku-with-mbstring/

Comment: That doesn't work anymore with the new, official version of Heroku's PHP support. There's a standard way to enable extensions via `composer.json` instead.