# Facebook PHP SDK v4 return blank page on server but working in localhost

Tags: php, server, facebook-php-sdk

Everything is working perfect in localhost, but not working on server. (showing blank page for Chrome, and show HTTP 500 internal server error in IE. I tried to get error log by adding code at the top of php file but failed to obtain log but a blank page)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Server is running with PHP 5.5, with CURL SSL enabled. I've tried to set the server IP to whitelist in facebook setting, but not working as well. Facebook id and secret in server are correct.

I am using Facebook Javascript SDK to obtain user access token

```
FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
```

Then pass to facebook.php by AJAX for checking and getting user profile

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "facebook.php",
    data: 'access_token='+access_token
```

**facebook.php**

```
require 'FB_php_sdk_v4/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app_id', 'app_secret');
$session = new FacebookSession($_POST['access_token']);

// get GraphUser info by Facebook API
try {
  $me = (new FacebookRequest(
    $session, 'GET', '/me'
  ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
  $first_name = $me->getFirstName();
  $uid = $me->getId();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
  $code = $e->getCode();
  $error_msg = $e->getMessage();
  echo $code.$error_msg;
}
```

I tried to different scenario and found when FacebookRequest is executed, the page will turn blank.

```
$me = (new FacebookRequest(
        $session, 'GET', '/me'
      ))->execute()->
```

I've been stucked at here for few days >< hope someone can help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: anyone has idea why I cannot make FacebookRequest in live server?

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause.

The error cannot be shown because I hide it in some code, so after putting the error display code after those error hiding code, error was found.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Error is

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Facebook\mb_substr() in /xxx/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php on line 253
```

And following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140186/facebook-php-sdk-error-mb-substr) , just enable the mbstring in server and problem is solved!

Hope this can help someone who encountered similar issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think its missing

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(URL_REDIRECT);
```

Ref : 
https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/